# php mail returns FALSE while error_get_last() returns NULL

Tags: php, email

Like the title says, mail returns FALSE to I call error_get_last() and it returns a NULL. The email is never received. The thing is, nearly identical code in another page on this site has no problem sending an HTML email, so the server must be okay.

I searched and found this question "PHP mail() returns false but no error is logged", but the answer doesn't seem to apply in my case.

My php code is:

```
<?php
$MSG_Info = array(
'', //  0 = Sender's name
'', //  1 = Sender's email address
'', //  2 = Subject of the message
'');//  3 = The message itself

$MSG_SendTo ='XXXX@yahoo.com';

function GetMessageText()
{
global $MSG_Info;

  return
    "<blockquote>". 
    "Name: ".$MSG_Info[0]."<br />".
    "Email: ".$MSG_Info[1]."<br />".
    "Subject: ".$MSG_Info[2]."<br />".
    "Message: ".wordwrap($MSG_Info[3], 70, "\r\n")."<br />".
    "</blockquote>";
}

function GetHTMLHeader()
{
  return
    '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">'.
    '<html>'.
    '<head>'.
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">'.
    '<title>Marguerite Gabe Braun</title>'.
    '</head>'.
    '<body>'.
    '<p><font size="+2" color="#0000AA">'.
    '<i>A Message from Marguerite&#8217;s Web Site</font></i></p>';
}

function SendMessageEmail($Dest)
{
    global $MSG_Info, $MSG_SendTo;

    $from =     $MSG_SendTo;
    $subject =  $MSG_Info[2];

    $message = GetHTMLHeader(); 

    switch ($Dest)
    {
      case 1:
        $to = $MSG_SendTo;
        $replyto =  $MSG_Info[1];
        $message .= "<p>".$MSG_Info[0]." has sent you a message from your web site.</p>\n";
      break;

      case 2:
        $to = $MSG_Info[1];
        $replyto =  $MSG_SendTo;
        $message .= "<p>Here is the message you sent to Marguerite Gabe Braun from her web site.</p>\n"; 
      break;

      default:
        $to = $MSG_SendTo;
        $replyto =  $MSG_SendTo;
        $message .= "<p>".$MSG_Info[0]." has sent you a message from your web site.</p>\n";
    }

    $message .= "<p>".GetMessageText()."</p>\n"."</body></html>";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "From: " . $from . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . PHP_EOL;

    // Send the email.
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $MSG_Result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($MSG_Result)
    {
      $MSG_Error = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      $MSG_Error = error_get_last();
    }
    return $MSG_Error;
}
?>
```

I've inserted all kinds of code (not shown here) to verify that I'm not screwing up the email addresses, that mail() is indeed returning FALSE, and error_get_last() is returning NULL, that the correct information is being passed in POST, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Edit.

Brute force debugging, commenting out one line at a time, narrowed it down the the line in the header where I specify "From:". If I comment out that line the mail sends and it says it is from the webmaster at my site.

So I test more and it looks like the word "From:", or any line that starts with that, is removed from my message. So strange. See the code below. The code for $message for the Reply-to lines, the line with three "froms" in it, and the simple $from line show in the message in my email. All others are missing. Or maybe this is clearer. Message lines 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 10 show in my message. The others, which all start with "From:", do not. It's the dangest thing.

```
<?php
$message .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$message .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$message .= "From: "."\r\n";
$message .= "FROM: "."\r\n";
$message .= "From, from, FROM: "."\r\n";
$message .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$message .= $from."\r\n";
$message .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$message .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$message .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$message .= "<p>".GetMessageText()."</p>\n"."</body></html>";

// This commented-out code is used on another page and with works correctly.
//  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
//  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
//  $headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
//  $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
//  $headers .= "From: " . $from . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . PHP_EOL;

// Send the email.
$MSG_Result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($MSG_Result)
{
  $MSG_Error = NULL;
}
else
{
  $MSG_Error = error_get_last();
    if ($MSG_Error == NULL) {$MSG_Error[0] = "Unknown mail() error.";}
}
return $MSG_Error;
}
?>
```

Comment: You shoud use a package to send email more complete (PHPMailer for example) to get more informations about the error.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. I'm a rookie at this, self-taught at the school of Google, so I could easily get in over my head. Plus, I'm using a hosting service. This is not on servers I manage.

Comment: Brute force debugging, commenting out one line at a time, showed that the header line listing the "from" item was causing the problem. With it commented out, the mail sends, and the email says it was sent by the webmaster at my site.